# Problems with zoom and menu (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to load an image from a menu, and then do zoom in and out to the image.

The problem is that my program doesn't execute the menu and launch ​​directly the image load. How I can fix it?

Thanks!

```
from Tkinter import *
import Image, ImageTk,tkFileDialog

class LoadImage:
    def __init__(self,root):
        frame = Frame(root)
        self.canvas = Canvas(frame,width=900,height=900)
        self.canvas.pack()
        frame.pack()
        options={}
        options['defaultextension']='.gif'
        options['filetypes']=[('GIF','.gif'),('JPEG','.jpg'),('TIFF','.tif')]
        options['title']='Select image file'
        File=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(**options)
        self.orig_img = Image.open(File)
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.orig_img)
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image=self.img, anchor="nw")
        self.zoomcycle = 0
        self.zimg_id = None
        root.bind("<MouseWheel>",self.zoomer)
        self.canvas.bind("<Motion>",self.crop)

    def zoomer(self,event):
        if (event.delta > 0):
            if self.zoomcycle != 4: self.zoomcycle += 1
        elif (event.delta < 0):
            if self.zoomcycle != 0: self.zoomcycle -= 1
        self.crop(event)

    def crop(self,event):
        if self.zimg_id: self.canvas.delete(self.zimg_id)
        if (self.zoomcycle) != 0:
            x,y = event.x, event.y
            if self.zoomcycle == 1:
                tmp = self.orig_img.crop((x-45,y-30,x+45,y+30))
            elif self.zoomcycle == 2:
                tmp = self.orig_img.crop((x-30,y-20,x+30,y+20))
            elif self.zoomcycle == 3:
                tmp = self.orig_img.crop((x-15,y-10,x+15,y+10))
            elif self.zoomcycle == 4:
                tmp = self.orig_img.crop((x-6,y-4,x+6,y+4))
            size = 300,200
            self.zimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(tmp.resize(size))
            self.zimg_id = self.canvas.create_image(event.x,event.y,image=self.zimg)

root = Tk()
root.title("Crop Test")
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Abrir", command=LoadImage(root))
menubar.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=filemenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filemenu.add_command(label="Abrir", command=LoadImage(root))
```

The `command=LoadImage(root)` will instantiate your LoadImage class, and call the file dialog. You want to

- Separate the file open action of your class in a separate method (say 'abrir')
- Instantiate the class separately from the GUI functions (eg. li = LoadImage())
- Connectthe 'abrir' method to the Abrir button in the menu

Separating like this:

```
li = LoadImage(root)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Abrir", command = li.abrir)
```

It is always better to separate the creation of the classes separately.
Here's the corrected code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Image, ImageTk,tkFileDialog

class LoadImage:
    def __init__(self,root):
        frame = Frame(root)
        self.canvas = Canvas(frame,width=900,height=900)
        self.canvas.pack()
        frame.pack()
        self.zoomcycle = 0
        self.zimg_id = None
        root.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.zoomer)
        self.canvas.bind("<Motion>", self.crop)

    def abrir(self):
        File = "nlx019PQVT1sidekro1_540.jpg"
        options={}
        options['defaultextension']='.gif'
        options['filetypes']=[('GIF','.gif'),('JPEG','.jpg'),('TIFF','.tif')]
        options['title']='Select image file'
        File=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        self.orig_img = Image.open(File)
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.orig_img)
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0,image=self.img, anchor="nw")

    def zoomer(self,event):
        if (event.delta > 0):
            if self.zoomcycle != 4: self.zoomcycle += 1
        elif (event.delta < 0):
            if self.zoomcycle != 0: self.zoomcycle -= 1
        self.crop(event)

    def crop(self, event):
        if self.zimg_id: self.canvas.delete(self.zimg_id)
        if (self.zoomcycle) != 0:
            x,y = event.x, event.y
            if self.zoomcycle == 1:
                tmp = self.orig_img.crop((x-45,y-30,x+45,y+30))
            elif self.zoomcycle == 2:
                tmp = self.orig_img.crop((x-30,y-20,x+30,y+20))
            elif self.zoomcycle == 3:
                tmp = self.orig_img.crop((x-15,y-10,x+15,y+10))
            elif self.zoomcycle == 4:
                tmp = self.orig_img.crop((x-6,y-4,x+6,y+4))
            size = 300,200
            self.zimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(tmp.resize(size))
            self.zimg_id = self.canvas.create_image(event.x,event.y,image=self.zimg)

root = Tk()
root.title("Crop Test")
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

li = LoadImage(root)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Abrir", command = li.abrir)
menubar.add_cascade(label = "Archivo", menu = filemenu)
root.config(menu = menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Note: I didn't check if the rest of the code works - but the file open problem is solved here :)

Comment: I want Instantiate the class separately from the GUI functions (eg. li = LoadImage()). My problem is that the option "LoadImage" of the menu appears before the menu.

Comment: OMG! A lot of thanks! :DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD